# .NET Start Process with higher rights

Tags: c#, .net, process, admin-rights

I am trying to execute a program with admin rights through a C# application, which gets invoked with user rights only.

Code

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi;
        try
        {
            psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"WINZIP32.EXE");

            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            SecureString pw = new SecureString();
            pw.AppendChar('p');
            pw.AppendChar('a');
            pw.AppendChar('s');
            pw.AppendChar('s');   
            pw.AppendChar('w');
            pw.AppendChar('o');
            pw.AppendChar('r');
            pw.AppendChar('d');
            psi.Password = pw;
            psi.UserName = "administrator";

            Process.Start(psi);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

It does start winzip, but only with user rights. Is there something I am doing wrong or is it even possible to start a process with higher rights?

thank you!

Edit:
Here is the reason behind the question, maybe it helps to understand what i actually need.

> I used winzip for example to get a general idea what's incorrect with my code. The actual problem is, our company uses 2 versions of a program. But before you start any of the versions you need to import a dll file with regsvr32 (with admin rights). Now I would like to write a program that let the user select the version, import the dll and starts the correct application.

Comment: Do you mean I should start my application with admin rights, then yes I tried it and it's weird but it also opens winzip with user rights. But either way, the c# program will be executed from a user without admin rights. **EDIT:** The comment i replied to, was deleted.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to `true` and [ProcessStartInfo.Verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx) to `runas`:

```
Process process = null;
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

processStartInfo.FileName = "WINZIP32.EXE";

processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

This will cause the application to run as the administrator. UAC will however prompt the user to confirm. If this is not desirable then you'll need to add a [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to permanently elevate the host process privilages.

Comment: The user shouldn't need to enter the admin password. Winzip should start with the admin account I define inside the code.

Comment: UAC is there for a reason. No well designed application should need to run an unzip process as Administrator.

Comment: I used winzip for example to get a general idea what's incorrect with my code. The actual problem is, our company uses 2 versions of a program. But before you start any of the versions you need to import a dll file with regsvr32 (with admin rights). Now I would like to write a program that let the user select the version, import the dll and starts the correct application.

Comment: But setting UseShellExecute = true, doesn't allow to redirect the output. Is there any way to get an admin process's output in a non-admin process?

Answer (score 3):

You can run a process as another user(even an administrator) using the [CreateProcessAsUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Win32 API).
CreateProcessAsUser accepts a user token as the first parameter, that is an impersonation token.

You have to use DLLImport to load the function from the Windows DLL.

Take a look at this example implementation that i have used in one of my projects :

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public uint nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;

}

internal enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation
}

internal enum TOKEN_TYPE
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation
}

public class ProcessAsUser
{

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    uint dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
    IntPtr hExistingToken,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    Int32 ImpersonationLevel,
    Int32 dwTokenType,
    ref IntPtr phNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
    IntPtr ProcessHandle,
    UInt32 DesiredAccess,
    ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
    ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    IntPtr hToken,
    bool bInherit);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
    IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
    IntPtr hObject);

    private const short SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private const uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private const uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private const int GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS = 0x10000000;
    private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
    private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
    private const uint CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
    private const int STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN = 0x00000020;

    private static bool LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock)
    {
        bool result = false;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saProcess.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
        saThread.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);

        //if this member is NULL, the new process inherits the desktop
        //and window station of its parent process. If this member is
        //an empty string, the process does not inherit the desktop and
        //window station of its parent process; instead, the system
        //determines if a new desktop and window station need to be created.
        //If the impersonated user already has a desktop, the system uses the
        //existing desktop.

        si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default"; //Modify as needed
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

        //Set other si properties as required.

        result = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        null,
        cmdLine,
        ref saProcess,
        ref saThread,
        false,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        envBlock,
        null,
        ref si,
        out pi);

        if (result == false)
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LaunchProcess As User Overloaded for Window Mode 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdLine"></param>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <param name="envBlock"></param>
    /// <param name="WindowMode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock,uint WindowMode)
    {
        bool result = false;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saProcess.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
        saThread.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);

        //if this member is NULL, the new process inherits the desktop
        //and window station of its parent process. If this member is
        //an empty string, the process does not inherit the desktop and
        //window station of its parent process; instead, the system
        //determines if a new desktop and window station need to be created.
        //If the impersonated user already has a desktop, the system uses the
        //existing desktop.

        si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default"; //Default Vista/7 Desktop Session
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;

        //Check the Startup Mode of the Process 
        if (WindowMode == 1)
            si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
        else if (WindowMode == 2)
        { //Do Nothing
        }
        else if (WindowMode == 3)
            si.wShowWindow = 0; //Hide Window 
        else if (WindowMode == 4)
            si.wShowWindow = 3; //Maximize Window
        else if (WindowMode == 5)
            si.wShowWindow = 6; //Minimize Window
        else
            si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;


        //Set other si properties as required.
        result = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        null,
        cmdLine,
        ref saProcess,
        ref saThread,
        false,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        envBlock,
        null,
        ref si,
        out pi);

        if (result == false)
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }

        return result;
    }

    private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(int processId)
    {
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool retVal = false;
        Process p = null;

        try
        {
            p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        }

        catch (ArgumentException)
        {

            string details = String.Format("ProcessID {0} Not Available", processId);
            Debug.WriteLine(details);
            throw;
        }

        //Gets impersonation token
        retVal = OpenProcessToken(p.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token);
        if (retVal == true)
        {

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            //Convert the impersonation token into Primary token
            retVal = DuplicateTokenEx(
            token,
            TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY,
            ref sa,
            (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
            (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
            ref primaryToken);

            //Close the Token that was previously opened.
            CloseHandle(token);
            if (retVal == false)
            {
                string message = String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
            }

        }

        else
        {

            string message = String.Format("OpenProcessToken Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }

        //We'll Close this token after it is used.
        return primaryToken;

    }

    private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
    {

        IntPtr envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool retVal = CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false);
        if (retVal == false)
        {

            //Environment Block, things like common paths to My Documents etc.
            //Will not be created if "false"
            //It should not adversley affect CreateProcessAsUser.

            string message = String.Format("CreateEnvironmentBlock Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }
        return envBlock;
    }

    public static bool Launch(string appCmdLine /*,int processId*/)
    {

        bool ret = false;

        //Either specify the processID explicitly
        //Or try to get it from a process owned by the user.
        //In this case assuming there is only one explorer.exe

        Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        int processId = -1;//=processId
        if (ps.Length > 0)
        {
            processId = ps[0].Id;
        }

        if (processId > 1)
        {
            IntPtr token = GetPrimaryToken(processId);

            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                IntPtr envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
                ret = LaunchProcessAsUser(appCmdLine, token, envBlock);
                if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock);

                CloseHandle(token);
            }

        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: How do you subscribe to `Process.Exited` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx with this approach? Also it does not seem to be able to accept custom `EnvironmentBlock` in .net friendly format like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Ideally I'm looking for solution that does everything that stock standard Process can do, but also accept a token. Looks like I'm going to have to build one myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ref:
 [How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)
[Elevating process privilege programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

```
  var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "notepad",
        UserName = "admin",
        Domain = "",
        Password = pass,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        Verb = "runas";
    };
    Process.Start(psi);
```

//

```
var pass = new SecureString();
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('e');
pass.AppendChar('c');
pass.AppendChar('r');
pass.AppendChar('e');
pass.AppendChar('t');
Process.Start("notepad", "admin", pass, "");
```

**//Vista or higher check**

```
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
   p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
```

**Ref:** [How to run/start a new process with admin rights?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303870.aspx/1)  ASP.net Forum

> Another way is to impersonate the admin user. You can do this by
>   calling the Logon function and impersonate the user whose token you
>   will get then. For impersonating a user in code, look at:
>   [WindowsImpersonationContext
>   Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)
>   . Use the check
>   http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=31611 for
>   GetCurrentUser to see whether impersonation succeeded.

Code Snippet:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo;

processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

processStartInfo.FileName = "regedit.exe";

if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)  // Windows Vista or higher
{
   processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
else
{
   // No need to prompt to run as admin
}

processStartInfo.Arguments = "";
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

try
{
   process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
finally
{
   if (process != null)
   {
      process.Dispose();
   }
}
```

**//Try this with administrator login, i have not tested yet..**

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        // Test harness.
        // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
            bool returnValue = LogonUser("administrator", "", "password",
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser called.");

            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret);
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + (returnValue ? "Yes" : "No"));
                Console.WriteLine("Value of Windows NT token: " + safeTokenHandle);

                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: "
                    + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
                WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo;


                    processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

                    processStartInfo.FileName = "regedit.exe";

                    //if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)  // Windows Vista or higher
                    //{
                    //    processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    // No need to prompt to run as admin
                    //}

                    processStartInfo.Arguments = "";
                    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

                    try
                    {
                        process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (process != null)
                        {
                            process.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                    // Check the identity.
                    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "
                        + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                }
                // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation
                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("After closing the context: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first way is exactly the same I do and it doesn't work. The second one opens the UAC, thats not what I need. When i use the impersonate function, I get a "access denied" exception.

Comment: UAC is doing what it was designed to. You would have to turn UAC off to get around that. Its by design. You're not supposed to run elevated processes without approval from the user.