# how to copy a file from any directory to c drive using cmd in c#

Tags: c#, file-io

i tried an image file to copy in c:(operating sys) drive,but it says error wid access denied,i have used as

```
string strCmdLine;
    strCmdLine = @" /c xcopy d:\123.png C:\windows\system32";
    Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
```

Comment: try the same arguments in the cmd shell and see if it succeeds b4 trying it from code.

Comment: `xcopy` is a native program, not a shell built-in. You don't need to run it through `cmd`.

Comment: do you really need to use the command line? there are already several builtin classes which can do this job, too. using the command shell is not very easy if you want to handle possible exceptions/failors (especially evaluation of a problem beneath the returning result). See System.IO namespace and FileInfo/File classes at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library./system.io%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you want (or need) to put an image to C:\windows\system32? This is not a good/common practice... you should (re)think about your software requirements and architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run CMD.exe as admin try following

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.Start();

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"/c xcopy d:\123.png C:\windows\system32");
```

You can check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp) post which shows how to run program as admin.

Answer (score 1):

you probably dont have enough permissions....

try adding credentials :

```
    Process p = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UserName = "aaaa";  
    process.StartInfo.Password = "xxxxx";
...
...
```

also  , verify that :

read permissions for : `d:\123.png`

write permissions for : `C:\windows\system32`

Comment: sir but if we wanna make a application in which user browse his own picture & then application copy it to c: drive then how would it take permission?

Answer (score 1):

Access Denied may be caused by several reasons, such as user permissions or file being in use. Since the command line seems to be OK, I suggest to check whether your application was run by a Windows user that has permission to write to C:\windows\system32.