# main program of console application is called twice in c# when called from web application

Tags: c#, console

i have console application and web application.
i am calling the main program of console from web application like this

#### Web

```
 public void RunconsoleApplication(string CanpaignId) {
        // Get the file path of your Application (exe)
        string filePath = @"E:/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe";

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath, CanpaignId);

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
        p.Start();
    }
```

#### Console

```
Class program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("start without arg");
        if (args.Length > 0) {  
            Program p = new Program();
            // This is another function in the class, not copied here
            p.CreateCanpaign(Convert.ToInt64(args[0]));                

            Console.WriteLine("stop");             
        } 
    }
}
```

now can someone explain why this function 'CreateCanpaign(a)' is called twice. i am new to console applications. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of these two lines, you are starting it twice

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
p.Start();
```

Remove `p.Start();`

Comment: so p.start() should not be included??

Comment: ahh.. i know that was simple thing to ask.. but sometimes these little things are difficult to find out.. thankyou very much .. :)

Comment: plz can you tell me one thing more.. i am calling this function as a user. how can i call it as an administrator with username and password.. i have tried some code but it is not working..

Comment: @DollyDar, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp