# Starting an Application as Administrator from another one

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows-7, uac

I'm a little lost here.

I have an App, let's call it App1.

App1 works fine. In some cases, App1 needs to execute another program, App2.

The code is simple:

```
           /*call app2*/
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathActualizador"]));

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en parármetros enviados al Actualizador..", Properties.Resources.txtTituloAplicacion, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            /*close app1 and letting app2 do its work*/
            Application.ExitThread();
```

In some cases, I've problem with the authorization for calling app2.
App1 is a simple system, app2 needs to create, move and delete some files and folders (that's why is giving me trouble)
At least, we solve it executing as an administrator de app2, by right click --> properties --> execute as administrator.

I'm trying to solve this.
I've read many posts, about creating a manifest file here in SO.
So, I created one.
I added the new item from Application project --> add new item --> app.manifest

And by the default created, only changed this

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

THIS MANIFEST is for App1.
We have both apps in like 100 computers, and we can't  change it one by one (most of them are in another country)
But we have an application to modify, sending some commands throw Internet, the app1.
So, I've read that if a process create another one, this new process will have the same ExecutionLevel that its parent. So, adding the manifest in App1, when it creates Process for App2, should execute as Administrator

I'm right or not?

By the other hand, I've added the manifest, compiled, and sent the .exe and .manifest to a client, run, and I still have the same problem: The app2 cannot access to folders to modify them, returning a problem of  privileges.

Is there something wrong ? I've to create a manifest for the App2 instead? This is kinda difficult, also is difficult to configure windows for each machine..

I've read that I can also do something like

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

but also read that in the future (said this in 2008) that this could be ignored, and the only way will be using manifest. So I want to avoid this option

edit: Using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 3.5

edit2: I've tried "runas", also not working. The user is no administrator, so has no rights of administrator

Comment: Why not just mock this up in a VM and try it out for yourself?

Comment: the first option does not work; I've said that already tried. The second one could work, but I'm saying that I want to avoid that because it will be ignored in the future.

Comment: I posted an answer below, as this should not require admin credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the WorkingDirectory, maybe you try to run App2 from the WorkingDir of App1

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.WorkingDirectory ="SomePath";
```

**EDITED:**

I found an entry on SO which could help you: 
[How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: In win xp, and some win 7 clients with user administrator works well, So I guess is the right Path. Also, In the Event Viewer log the correct path that cannot access

Answer (score 0):

I will make the recommendation that you don't need administrative credentials:

> app2 needs to create, move and delete some files and folders (that's
>   why is giving me trouble)

Nothing in the statement proves you need to be an admin.  I would recommend revisiting the architecture of your program.  The first step I would take is to have two separate users on your system.  A user for `app1` and a user for `app2` lets call them `App1User` and `App2User` respectively.  Now the configuration for both of these users should be as follows:

Non-privileged, cannot log in, can only execute their respective programs, and do not have permissions to anything not directly controlled by them.

Now from here `App1User` can delegate to `App2User` to execute `app2`, this prevents any privilege escalation from occurring and removes the need for admin.  Now `App2User` needs to be able to create,move, and delete things that it owns.  That should not be a problem, as a regular user I can create,delete, and move things that I own.  There are very few reasons why something needs to run as admin or root.

**UPDATE**

In reply to the following:

> The problem is when App1 need to call App2 so App2 can do some tasks.
>   App1 doesn't need to create folders or anything, so has no problem
>   with UAC. App2 does

Ok so from the ground up we will have the following three system objects:

```
AppUser1,AppUser2, AppUserGroup
```

The `AppUserGroup` will contain both `AppUser1` and `AppUser2` .  The `AppUserGroup` will need to be locked down similar to the app users.  The way the permissions will need to be configured is as follows:

`App1` is owned by AppUserGroup and has at the very least execute permissions.
`App2` is owned by AppUserGroup and has at the very least execute permissions.

Make sure the permissions are also granted to the users within the group.  Now what this allows you to do is invoke the program as `AppUser1` which is a member of the `AppUserGroup` and run `App2` by virtue of being inside of the group and that group owning the process.  Let me know if this needs further clarification.

Comment: The problem is that the user actually has no permision to write - I want to avoid that, programatically, because creating users or giving permissions to windows user is complicated - Like 100 clients to configure. But if there's no other way..

Comment: Wait is this a thick client type application or a web application?

Comment: Ok is are you installing this via installshield or something of that nature?  I will update my answer to make it a bit more straight forward.

Comment: it's allready installed. The problem is when App1 need to call App2 so App2 can do some tasks. App1 doesn't need to create folders or anything, so has no problem with UAC. App2 does

Comment: You should be able to make a PowerShell script to configure your clients. With 100 or so clients, it is really handy to learn and use PS.