# C# Process.Start() administrator privileges on Windows Embedded POSReady 2009

Tags: c#, windows, privileges, administrator

I am attempting to call a batch file with administrator privileges in some C# code using `System.Diagnostic`'s `Process.Start()` as mentioned here:
[How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp) .

I call the built executable from an elevated command prompt as well as with `runas /user:administrator program.exe`. The subprocess succeeds when called outside of my program, but fails at its administrator tasks when called by my program.

I have attempted using a manifest and setting the `Process.Verb = "runas"`, but no luck there.

The subprocess installs a driver and my program verifies the version number if that's relevant.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does your program run with administrative privileges? Any process you spawn from your program will have the same privileges as the process that spawns it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following lines in your application's manifest:

```
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

Your application will spawn other processes at the same elevation level as itself. Meaning that if your application runs as a non-administrator, every process it spawns will run without administrative permissions, too.

Make sure your parent application has elevated permissions before you start your batch file.

Comment: That's what I assumed happened, and the task manager reports that the subprocess is being run with the administrator account, but somehow the privileges aren't there because the driver is not being installed.

Comment: Well, if it runs under the administrator's account it could still be run without administrative privileges. You need to explicitly require administrator in your application manifest to obtain elevated permissions.

Comment: I have tried setting the requestedExecutionLevel again for my program, and I have verified that it is running with administrator privileges (tested with file/registry modification). Is there a way to specify the requestedExecutionLevel for a batch file? The subprocess still doesn't have the same privileges the main program has.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out administrator privileges are only given to executables when using `runas`, so you can't call the batch file directly. Instead of `p.StartInfo.FileName = program.bat`, you should call it with `p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"` and `p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /C ..."`.