# Run a command line program as Administrator

Tags: c#, command-line, admin

I need to run this as an administrator

```
string cname = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
string resetTrust = "netdom /resetpwd /s:server01 /ud:" + cname + "/pd:" + textBoxPassword.Text.Trim();
String output = ExecuteCommandAsAdmin(resetTrust);
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Here is the method ExecuteCommandAsAdmin

```
public static string ExecuteCommandAsAdmin(string command)
{
    string cname = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

    ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = "runas.exe",
        Arguments = "/user:" + cname + "\"cmd /K " + command + "\""
    };

    using (Process proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            output = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        return output;
    }
}
```

If you know a better way to do this, please let me know. I am not storing the password. Just passing it so it can be executed. If the wrong person enters the wrong password, nothing happens since they aren't an Admin.

Thank You

Comment: i don't see a problem... you aren't hard coding anything.  this probably isn't a `legit` SO question as you don't have a coding question.  You are asking for more opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a Process as administrator mode in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Define what you mean by running as administrator.

Comment: Administrator is a user or a group that contains users in it. Not all commands execute with a "Standard" account.

Comment: So which is it to be? You have to pick a user. The built in `Administrator`? Anyway, I think you are doing it wrong. I think you need to use either the `runas` verb to elevate, or use a manifest to force elevation at startup, or shell out to an executable that has that manifest. Why did you choose to try to shell out to `runas.exe`?

Comment: did you see my code above? it's not working as expected. The output should be "This command as completed successfully" but I get a ""

Comment: Yes I did see the code above. But you did not explain what you were trying to do, nor did you explain how the code failed to meet your expectations. Do you want to let me help you solve the problem, or would you rather I lent my help to somebody else?

Comment: I am trying to reset the trust relationship between a workstation and the server.

Comment: Are you trying to elevate, or run the process as a specific user?

Comment: The user is the person that is currently logged in. I am not checking if the user is an admin. It won't work if they aren't an admin since group policies prevent runas for stanard users.

Comment: I think you aren't understanding. I am a sysadmin. I am also the developer. I am trying to run 1 command with elevated privs. I can accomplish the same task using Command Prompt (Run As Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Use `runas /user:name@domain cmd`