# Writing a cmd Command in a Console Application

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application

I'm trying to write a C# console application that will launch `runas.exe` through cmd then run another application as that user.  I've taken one of the suggestions listed below (and added a little bit) as it seems the most promising.

```
Process cmd = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/K C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\USER'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe\'")
{
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
cmd.StartInfo = startinfo;
cmd.Start();
StreamWriter stdInputWriter = cmd.StandardInput;
stdInputWriter.Write("PASSWORD");
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

When I launch the application it asks for the password before the command itself causing there to be an error with `runas.exe`

[image]

I'm pretty sure `UseShellExecute = false` is causing the error but the `StreamWriter` doesn't work without it so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you tried:
stdInputWriter.WriteLine("password");

?
Maybe you just didn't confirmed input?

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz but I would still need to declare the streamwriter and if I don't do it with `Process.StandardInput` than what should I do declare it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532782/2817312).  I had  to forgo most of the structure I was working with but I can now successfully run notepad as my desired user with the code listed below.

```
var pass = new SecureString();
pass.AppendChar('p');
pass.AppendChar('a');
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('w');
pass.AppendChar('o');
pass.AppendChar('r');
pass.AppendChar('d');
var runFileAsUser = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "notepad",
    UserName = "username",
    Domain = "domain",
    Password = pass,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
Process.Start(runFileAsUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

The /c argument runs comman line and terminates, so you could not see results (and it's a large C), see her :  http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Try to use "/K".
I did it with your command and i see results in another window.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/K ping PC -t");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Good stuff! This lets me run commands and see them now I have to figure out how to input a C# variable into cmd

Comment: @BlueBarren   thanks, you could even mark the answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your process should have [RedirectStandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) = true

```
var p  = new Process();
var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C C:\temp\input.bat")
{
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
p.StartInfo = startinfo;
p.Start();
StreamWriter stdInputWriter = p.StandardInput;           
stdInputWriter.Write("y");
```

This program launches input.bat, and then sends the value `y` to it's standard input.

For completeness, `input.bat` example:

```
set /p input=text?: 
echo %input%
```

Comment: I'm using `"/K"` so I can see what the cmd window is doing and yet it's still closing, why is that? It was working before.  Either way I'm not sure your method is working because the command I'm trying is to launch notepad and yet it isn't coming up.

Comment: Running notepad with both /K and /C works in my environment, is notepad in the path?

Comment: The path is `c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe\` and I know it works because when I was trying @MarksimSimkin 's answer the cmd command worked properly