# How to block access to URL

Tags: c#, url, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to write a Unity3d Project that can restrain my access to certain URL. For example, if I want to block Youtube.com, it will block my access to youtube.com from all my browsers.

I see that in C# program you can use System.Windows.Form class to do it. But Unity3D don't have access to use System.Windows.Form. Is there any built-in method that I can use to block URL using unity3d?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What, you are trying unity3d to block URL on web. Is this right approach? Unity3d is not made for this . You should make desktop application or browser extension or utility to do this job. I guess.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan But the thing is the project I'm working on needs a lot of 3D graphics. And I'm quite familiar with Unity3d. So yeaaaa

Comment: It is difficult for me to identitfy the relationship b/w 3d Graphics and restricting url on browser. anyhow best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any built-in method that I can use to block URL using
>   unity3d?

**No**

There is no built in method to do this. You have to create one yourself.

On way to do this is through the *hosts* file located at

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

*Example of adding websites to block in this file*:

To block stackoverflow:

```
127.0.0.1 www.stackoverflow.com
```

To block Google:

```
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

---

**Putting it in Code**:

**1**.Read the hosts file from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`  line by line with `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
string[] hostData = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts"));
```

**2**.Convert the `hostData` array to `List` with:

```
List<string> hostDataList = new List<string>(hostData );
```

**3**.To add url, simply make a function that takes string(url) as a parameter. Remove `http` from that url if there is one.

Loop through the `hostDataList` List and make sure that the url you want to add does not exist by checking it with `String.Contains`. If it does **not** exist, add it to the List:

```
string urlToBlock = "127.0.0.1" + " "+ url;
hostDataList.Add(urlToBlock);
```

**4**.To remove url, simply make a function that takes string(url) as a parameter. Remove `http` from that url if there is one.

Loop through the `hostDataList` List and make sure that the url you want to add **exist**. If it does not exist, return. If it exist, find the index then remove it from the `List`:

```
int index;
//Make sure that the Url exist before removing it
if (containsUrl(url, out index))
{
    hostDataList.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

*Note*:

The `containsUrl` function is simply a function that loops through the `hostDataList` List then checks if the provided string is found. If it is found return `true` and store the index in which the string is found to the `out` index parameter.

This is the prototype:

```
bool containsUrl(string url, out int index){...}
```

**5**.When you are done, save it by converting the hostDataList `List` back to array then saving it with `File.WriteAllLines`.

```
string savePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts");
string[] hostDataArray = hostDataList.ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(savePath, hostDataArray);
```

I know this works because I have done it before. With answer this, you should be able to get this done on Windows.

*Notice*:

For this to work, your application must be running with an administrator  privileges. There are many [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp) to do this.

If testing from Unity's Editor, right click on Unity logo and then choose *Run as administrator*.

Comment: Thank You very much for this very detailed answer, I will test this in a few days !

Comment: Sure. Update me how it went. Happy coding!

Comment: I finally got time to implement this in Unity, it's almost done. But there's one quick question, Is creating a proxy in Unity a better way of doing it? Using Network class. Since I'm also going to use my app cross-platform .           e.g. The only way to block URL on android without root is to create a proxy

Comment: I did not consider Android while answering this since it was not tagged. My solution is tested on Windows and works. The-same thing can be done on Mac and Linux so it should also work there. For Android, you have to use another method which is proxy. You can write a Java code then call if from C# as a plugin.

Comment: You can also use Unity's [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) to decide if you should call the Android or Windows/Linux/Mac version of the code.

Comment: Gotcha! So you mean while on mac/pc, I can call Java code from c# and on android just call the android SDK, am I getting you right? Thanks for the link

Comment: And also, It seems to have problem working on Mac. It doesn't have privileges to access hosts.  Is there any way I can request user authorization from Unity3d? I did some google but not much results. (FYI i also posted the question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443185/unity3d-request-user-authorisation-osx))

Comment: While on Windows/Mac/Linux, you can use the method in my answer. While on Android, you have to make a Java plugin that you call from C#. The examples for Android/Java are really **hard** to find on the Internet but [this](https://gist.github.com/madeye/4352485) and [this](https://gist.github.com/madeye/2297083) may be useful to you. You can Google Unity Java/C# plugin for how to call Java from C#.

Comment: As for the Mac problem you are having, I don't know. Maybe you should create a new question for that. There are good Mac users that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much!, I will look into it!