# Unity3d request user authorisation (OSX)

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, privileges

So basically my Unity program would need to modify hosts file on OSX and that need admin privilege. And i got the following Exception:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/private/etc/hosts" is denied.
```

How do I pop a "XXX wants to make changes: Enter your password to allow this." window just like the screenshot I attached below？

I did some Google but i couldn't find anything useful.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does the code fail? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Programmer yes i got a exception, i just modify the question.

Comment: What happens if you run it as admin on Mac?

Comment: @Programmer I run it by root using: sudo open "myapp.app/", but the development build still shows the same exception.

Comment: Your solution about Authorization service sounds promising. Go with that but update us if that works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more research, the only solution I can think off right now is to write a native plugin using apple's [Authorization service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html), and call it from Unity program.

But if there's a more Unity way of doing it, please don't hesitate to add it as an answer.

EDIT_1: Progress update and a note to my future self.

A native plugin for OSX is suffixed .bundle, I wrote it in C++(since the official example is in c++), but it dont have access to authorization service. And i don't know how to setup OC for a bundle project.  Now I'm trying an alternative to create a command-line tool application for OS X and run it as an external process from Unity3d.  Good news is now i can use swift to write it !

.

EDIT_2: Progress update and a note to my future self.

The commandline tool written in OC did work. I can simply open command line tool using Process.start(name, argument) in Unity3d.