# How to start a process in Administrator mode below Windows Vista?

Tags: c#

Recently, I'm trying to start a process in *Administrator Mode* in which the Windows version is **below Vista**. I was just trying to care about the program's compatibility` is there any method that I can start a program in *Administrator Mode* in OS which is **below Vista**?

Because I want the user to choose whether they want to run in *Administrator Mode* or not, therefore, I don't want to activate the program as *Administrator Mode* mode all the time.

***Note*** : Please do NOT mark me as duplication or rubbish question, I have read _[that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)_ page already. I didn't try does that **[method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp#2532775)** works in versions which is below Vista because I don't have much resources to do so.

Comment: "As of April 11, 2017, Windows Vista customers are no longer receiving new security updates, non-security hotfixes, free or paid assisted support options, or online technical content updates from Microsoft." - so anything below Vista  almost certainly has security flaws, and why would anyone be using it?

Comment: if you are using XP there is a good chance you are the source of all my email spam

Comment: Just because I want to care about the program's compatibility. In case if there are users which is still using versions below Vista.

Comment: @TheGeneral sorry I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: @MitchWheat umm...

Seriously, my school haven't updated all of the school computers. Therefore proves that there are still users of Windows using the XP version.

Comment: he means XP is so insecure that it will have been compromised by trojans, viruses, spam bots, crypto miners, DOS farms etc

Comment: I understand that, but just in case of there are still users who is still using it.

Comment: `lol surprising answer...`

>You can feel free to mark as duplicated then. Sorry for not noticing that post.