# Get exitcode from Process via arguments

Tags: c#, cmd, process

Im trying to start CMD process from my program that starts another process that redirect output and errors into file. And I have to have exit code of this process.

```
var exe = pathToExe
var output = Path.GetTempFileName();
var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
     FileName = "cmd",
     Arguments = $"/c "{exe} {command} > {output} 2<&1" & echo %errorlevel% > {output})", 
     Verb = "runas",
     UseShellExecute = true,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
});
                
process.WaitForExit();
var res = File.ReadAllText(output);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Same command (cmd /c "pathToExe command > output 2<&1" & echo %errorlevel% > output) worked fine in cmd, but in this code is errorlevel always 0 (I suggest its just errorlevel of cmd process)

At this point you may ask me why am I even using cmd to start process... Well, Ive tried

```
using (var process = CreateProcess(processName, argumnets))
{
    var error = 0;
    var output = Path.GetTempFileName();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";   
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{command} > {output} 2<&1";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    statusInfo = File.ReadAllText(output);
    File.Delete(output);
    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        error = process.ExitCode;
    }
    return error;
}
```

But it didnt work for me.
Also i cant redirect outputrs programmatically because of process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute.

Comment: What _specific_ process are you trying to start?  It is almost always wrong to start `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Its behing my program process, also written by me.
If its wrong, so how can I have to get outpur from process started with Verb = "runas"?

Comment: Well, I launched, there is a code of it. It didnt work for me

Comment: You can't do `{command} > {output} 2<&1"` since the latter bit is handled by the command interpreter (cmd.exe). Please explain why you want `2<&1`.

Comment: Because I want to have and STDOUT, and STDERR in my file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=net-5.0 is what you _should_ be using. Write them to a file in C# if you want that.

Comment: To use Process.StandardOutput and Process.StandardError I have to redirect it. I cant redirect due UseShellExecute.

Comment: Did you set `RedirectStandardError` etc?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I cant do it due UseShellExecute

Comment: Why do you think you need `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` to be `true`?

Comment: Because Im starting process as admin (```Verb = "runas"```). It won't work if ```UseShellExecute  = false```

Comment: Yes, this process changes Windows Registry

Comment: No, but it won't work without admin privilege

Comment: Have you considered a manifest - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN / https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533065/34092 ?

Comment: Yep, I tried this too. It didnt work for me.

Comment: [Code](https://pastebin.com/di6B9neB)
Manifest: ```<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />```
When I launch this code its says that I have to upper my privilege

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The requested operation requires elevation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...